# When solving $3xy'+y=12x$, why can absolute sign in ln |x| can be ignored?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the following is the differential equation:

$3xy'+y=12x$

We can solve this by

recasting the equation to $y'+y/3x=4$

and finding an integration factor.

Integration factor is: $e^{\int 1/3x \,\, dx} = e^{1/3 \ln |x|} = |x|^{1/3}$

But often it seems that absolute signs are ignored. Why is it the case? Does the result not change whether absolute sign is there or not?

Answer (score 2):

Depending where we are in the domain, the expression $|x|$ either means $x$ or $-x$. If we keep the absolute value sign, we're really just saying the expression in question is one thing for $x>0$ and another for $x<0$. The $x>0$ case is what you get when you just ignore the absolute value sign.

If you write out the $x<0$ case - which I encourage you to do - you'll do the same calculation, but using $-x^{1/3}$ as your integrating factor. You'll see that the minus sign immediately drops out, so it doesn't make any difference at all. That's why we don't bother with it.

Comment: If $x < 0$, then integrating factor is $(-x)^{\frac 13}$, not $-x^{\frac 13}$

Comment: @Kaster $(-x)^{\frac13}=-x^\frac13$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 in real analysis non-integer powers are not defined over negative numbers.

Comment: @Kaster, the $1/3$ power is defined for all reals. $f(x)=x^3$ is a one-to-one function, and $g(x)=x^{1/3}$ is its inverse.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, ok, so you claim that
$$
(-x)^{\frac 13} = -x^{\frac 13}
$$
but $(-x)^{\frac 13} = (-x)^{\frac 26} = \left ((-x)^2 \right )^{\frac 13} = x^{\frac 26}$. On the other hand
$$
-x^{\frac 13} = - x^{\frac 26}
$$
Contradiction?

Comment: That must be a typo, the outside exponent in your third expression. I would not agree that $x^{2/6}=(x^2)^{1/6}$, I would reduce the fraction first. That's a small sacrifice for having a reasonable way to write down the inverse of $x^3$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs that is not a sacrifice, that's a convention that teachers use in high school to let young students to wrap their heads around those concepts. It cause more confusion and frustration rather than use, so usually starting from college level math to have full consistency with all power related properties, like those I referred to, in real analysis non-integer powers are not defined over negative numbers. But if you insist, please, explain, how would you solve $2xy'+y = 12 x$?

Comment: I would use $\sqrt{x}$ as an integrating factor, and I wouldn't worry about the negative part of the domain, because I don't have to. I get $y=4x$ for my solution, and it works over its entire domain. How would you denote the inverse of $f(x)=x^3$, whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs what makes you think that integrating factor $\sqrt{-x}$ is somewhat bad if $x < 0$?

Comment: I didn't say $\sqrt{-x}$ is "somewhat bad" or in any way bad, did I? Where did you read that? I said that $\sqrt{x}$ works, because it does. Yours works, too, if you want to assume $x<0$. Fine. The point of an integrating factor is to get the job done, not to be defined on every point in the domain. What do you call the inverse of the cube function?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs hold on, you said that you don't have to consider $x < 0$, but why? Whatever solution you'll get will be valid only in right half-plane. As for the inverse, inverse is not the same as non-integer power. But just in case inverse of $y=x^3$ is 
$$
x = \left \{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
y^{\frac 13} & y \ge 0 \\
-(-y)^{\frac 13} & y < 0
\end{array}
\right .
$$

Comment: Except I did get a solution that was valid in the whole plane. Check my answer; it works. I see that you've got these ideas about how things have to be written, but I see no good reason for it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs would you please write down a solution that you got for the equation $2xy'+y=12x$ assuming only $x > 0$ part and presumably is valid for the entire domain?

Comment: I already did. Read my comment above. Or here, I'll retype it: $y=4x$. Check that it works.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I see, you completely ignored constant of integration, because if you didn't, you'd get $y = 4x + \frac C{\sqrt x}$, which is of course is invalid for $x < 0$, even though the problem does have a solution for that.

Comment: No. You keep assuming a lot of wrong stuff about what's going on in my head; please stop that. You asked for a solution valid on the whole domain, not for the general solution. I gave you precisely that. This particular differential equation has a singular point at $x=0$. If you just need any old solution, $4x$ works. If you need a particular solution that satisfies some initial condition, then you can write that down. The most general solution is defined piece-wise, with a $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{x}}$ term when $x>0$, and a ${c_2}{\sqrt{-x}}$ term when $x<0$. All solutions pass through $(0,0)$.

Comment: That should have been $\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{-x}}$ at the end there.

Comment: @kaster There is ambiguity in assuming that $x^{ab}=x^ax^b$ when $x$ is negative, even if you forbid allowing negative numbers to be raised to non-integer powers.  For example: $-1=(-1)^1\stackrel{?}{=}(-1)^{2\times\frac12}=((-1)^2)^{\frac12}=1^{\frac12}=1$.  So there is no reason to say that you can't define $-1^\frac13$ to be $-1$: just that if you want $x^{ab}$ to be equal to $x^ax^b$ for all $a,b$ then you need $x$ to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus signs are just in there to ensure that $\ln$ has a positive argument.  The general antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is $\ln(x)+c$.  Notice that $\ln(kx)=\ln(x)+\ln(k)$ so, since indefinite integrals are only defined up to an arbitrary constant, $\int \frac1xdx$ can take the value $\ln(kx)$ for any $k$.  In particular, since we don't normally want to take the logarithm of a negative number, we can set $\int\frac1xdx=\ln(x)+c$ for positive $x$ and $\int\frac1xdx=\ln(-x)+c$ for negative $x$.  This isn't a problem, since $\frac1x$ isn't defined at $0$ anyway, so we are never going to try to integrate $\frac1x$ over an interval that includes the point $0$.

If you are given the definite integral $\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac1xdx$, then you can use the antiderivative $\ln(|x|)$ to give you the answer $\ln(1)-\ln(2)=-\ln(2)$.  If the antiderivative were just $\ln(x)$ then you would run into difficulty trying to work out $\ln(-1)$.

When you try to find an integrating factor in your example, you are looking for $e^{F(x)}$, where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative for $\frac1{3x}$; i.e., $\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac1{3x}$.  Now, you *could* take $F(x)=\frac13\ln(|x|)$, and that would be a perfectly fine antiderivative.  However, taking $F(x)=\frac13\ln(x)$ gives you $x^{1/3}$, which is a bit easier to deal with.  Of course, if the exponent were $1/2$ rather than $1/3$ then you would want to use $|x|^{1/2}$ since you can't take the square root of a real number and end up with a real number.

Now, I'm sure you know that we can't take the logarithm of a negative number.  Why, then, is it OK to say our antiderivative $F$ is $\frac13\ln(x)$ for both positive and negative $x$?  One way we could deal with this problem is just to ignore the fact that we're doing something forbidden and just notice that it all ends up fine in the end when we pass to $e^{F(x)}$.  Another, slightly more enterprising, way to tackle the problem is just to pretend that $\ln(-1)$ has a value, and then notice the fact that $\ln(-x)=\ln(x.-1)=\ln(-1)$.  Thus we can now define $\ln$ of a negative number in terms of our new value $\ln(-1)$.  We can even do the integral $\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac1xdx$ without resorting to the messy $\ln(|x|)$ antiderivative: the integral is equal to $\ln(-1)-\ln(-2)=\ln(-1)-\ln(-1)-\ln(2)=-\ln(2)$.  Then our magical $\ln(-1)$ value disappears when we pass it through the exponential function: obviously, $e^{\ln(-1)}=-1$, and we are back to numbers that we are familiar with and didn't have to make up.

In fact, we can do even better that.  Perhaps you know the famous identity

$$
e^{i\pi}=-1
$$

where $i$ is the square root of $-1$ (which was itself originally invented in order to solve problems involving real numbers: terms involving $i$ appeared in the middle of calculations, but they had all disappeared by the end).  This means that we can take $\ln(-1)=i\pi$, and hence that $\ln(-x)=i\pi+\ln(x)$.  So, if we move to the complex numbers, we can do without the $\ln(|x|)$ construct altogether.

[In fact, there are some problems even with this approach, because we have to be careful in our definition of $\ln(-1)$.  For example, $e^{3i\pi}=-1$ as well, so why can't we take $\ln(-1)=3i\pi$?  In fact, this value works as well, but we have to choose one value (called choosing a *branch of the logarithm* and stick with that throughout.  That's fine for solving simple question like this one, though.  This seeming problem actually leads to some remarkable and beautiful mathematics in the field of complex analysis - in particular, the study of *Riemann surfaces*.]